# Help developing a very simple iPad application

Tags: iphone, ipad

I need to develop a very simple iPad application that takes RSS feed of images that will be updated constantly and will display them and you can slide through them. As simple as that.

Is there a way to get basic help on doing this, I am very new to iPhone/iPad development and would like help.

To make the question clearer, I would appreciate code samples (other than the ones displayed on Apple's developers site, tutorials, and guidelines.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first, you need to go through some Cocoa Touch tutorials and learn how all the pieces fit together. ;-)

Then check out some NSURLConnection samples on how to pull data down from the network.